# How to filter through list of objects like a search?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Car {
  late String make;
  late int year;

  Car({required this.make, required this.year});
}
```

How could I make a function that filters a list of Cars based on a query parameter?

Use this function as reference:

```
void filterCarsList(String query) {
  List<Car> cars = [
    Car(make: "Benz", year: 2021),
    Car(make: "BMW", year: 2016),
    Car(make: "Ford", year: 1999),
    Car(make: "Benz", year: 2009),
  ];
  List<Car> filteredList = [];

  filteredList = cars.where((e) => (e.make == query)).toList();

  print(filteredList);

  return;
}
```

What I am trying to do is `create a search functionality`.
**For Example:** if the `query == "b"`, then the 2 Benz and BMW objects should be in the filteredList. If the `query == "be"`, then the 2 Benz objects should be in the filteredList.

The function currently works however the entire string of `make` needs to be entered. For example, query needs to equal "Benz" for the Benz objects to be returned. I'm pretty sure I need to use RegEx but I don't really know where to start with that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is `make` is equal to `query` its means `make` and `query` should be same.

To solve this issue you need to use `contains` method just like this

`filteredList = cars.where((e) => (e.make.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))).toList();`

this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` function on the `string` to achieve this.

```
filteredList = cars.where((e) => (e.make.contains(query))).toList();
```

and to add the results from both the cases you can add

```
filteredList = cars.where((e) => (e.make.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowercase()))).toList();
```